# can't query by association field value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I need to query only `Realties` where user id confirmed.
I am using "devise" gem for authentication, and my query looks like this:

```
@search = Realty.includes(:user).where("users.confirmed_at != ?", nil)
```

As result I get `=> []`, but there are many `Realties` records where `user.confirmed? => true`. I double checked it from the console.

The association structure looks like this:

```
class Realty
     belongs_to :user
.....
class User
     has_many :realties
.....
```

Please help me or tell where I make an mistake ?? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@search = Realty.includes(:user).where("users.confirmed_at IS NOT NULL")
```

You cannot use `!=` in a SQL statement.

If you want to check if the value is not empty as well, then you can do

```
@search = Realty.includes(:user).where("users.confirmed_at <> ''")
```

it will return the results where `users.confirmed_at` is neither `null` nor `empty`.

Comment: Thank you Luís, this is the answer.

Comment: Can you help me with ordering this query? after `.where("users.confirmed_at IS NOT NULL")` I have `.order("created_at DESC")`, and I get an error `PG::Error: ERROR: column reference "created_at" is ambiguous`

Comment: Try `.order("users.created_at DESC")`

Comment: Figured this out to. I simply needed to use it with scope. Like this `.order("realties.created_at DESC")`

Comment: Great Andrey! Please accept my answer if it helped you, any other questions you should open a new question. Thank you

Comment: It seems like we added our comments in the same time :). Thank you very mach for your help.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure which records you wanted to order. Sorry about that, but glad you figured it out.